# Moving last li element to below the rest inline

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links that are displayed inline. I want the last li to be positioned centered of the inline list above it. How can I do this with css?

The reason for this is, when the web page is used in mobile it can't fit the entire list, so I want to move it below.

```
 <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Last Item</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `text-align:center` to both the `ul` and `li` element:

```
ul{
   list-style:none;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
}

ul li{
   text-align:center;
   display:inline-block;
   width:75px;
   height:20px;
   background:silver;
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:10px;
}
```

**IN ADDITION**: Make sure that the `ul` has a width of 100% and the `padding` of the `ul` is set to zero. Also, the `li` must have a display of `inline-block`.

Check out the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmj7q78t/

Comment: The only problem with this is they all fall below. Is there any way to keep the everything but the last one from moving below?

Answer (score 0):

This css will do the trick:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:last-child {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```